# "that...that" VS "such...that"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> ... (Ray's mother)Her dress hung badly on her body as if she had recently lost a lot of weight.
>
> "Ray," she(Ray's mother) said in **that** whispery conspirator's voice **that** he had come to dread. "Ray, listen --"
>
> He ducked his head and pretended to tuck in his shirt. ...

I think the use of first '*that*' is like '*such*': *she said in **such** whispery conspirator's voice **that** he had come to dread.*

So, I'm wondering if the form of "*that...that*" is common to replace "*such...that*". How should we understand it correctly here?

Excerpted from the book - "The Long Walk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first **that** is a colloquial use of the demonstrative adjective to refer to something the speaker believes the listener will recognize because the thing referenced is "out there" in the public consciousness

> You know **that** feeling where you could swear something has happened to you before?
>
> Our new Citrus Blitz has **that** fresh orange taste (that) you want in a soda.

or because the speaker recognizes it from a previous experience and wishes to point out that this is not the first encounter:

> There's that sound again.
>   -- What sound?
>   That scratching sound, over near the window.

In a story where the narrator reveals the mind of a character, this use indicates that the character recognizes the thing from previous encounter(s).

The second **that** in your example is the standard connector to a relative descriptive clause. It is modified by another clause "he had come to dread".

> The book (that) he took from the shelf was very dusty.
>
> The thing (that) he had in his pocket was the ring.